# Check if a task exists with grunt < 4.5

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I know they added a task.exists function in the version 4.5 of grunt. Is there any way to achieve the same with an older version?

```
// Fictional example

grunt.registerTask('build', function (target)
{
    target = target || 'stage';

    grunt.task.run([
        'clean:dist', 
        'copy:dist',
    ]);

    if (grunt.task.exists('replace.' + target)) {
        grunt.task.run(['replace:' + target]);
    }

});
```

Comment: I am assuming that you have read the git request for this functionality, and you would not use grunt.config ? https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/1047

Comment: @ovi: Thank you for the link. Just tried it. It does not seem to work for 'replace', 'replace.actual_target' nor for 'task.replace' with grunt 4.1. They're always undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the git request for this functionality, and apply the monkey patch : github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/1047

```
if (!grunt.task.exists) {
  grunt.task.exists = function exists (name) {
    return _.include(_.pluck(grunt.task._tasks, 'name'), name);
  };
}
```